# Drupal form editing and conditional fields

Tags: drupal, forms

I have the following in my template.php file:

```
function theme098_theme() {
  return array(
    'email_node_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    )
  );
}
```

and...

```
function theme098_email_node_form($form) {
    return drupal_render($form);
}
```

I've excluded the code where i actually modify the form and cut it down so that no modifications happen. Two problems occur:

1. The order of items (i.e. their weights) is messed up. The save button is at the top etc. Even if I try to edit the form by setting the weight, the save button STILL appears at the top.
2. The real problem: Conditional fields doesn't work. For some reason, I think this overwrites what other modules are supposed to do? I'm not sure

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 things.

1. In this case you should probably use [hook_form_alter()](http://d6-api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6), if you want to change the order or change the form, instead of using a theme function to alter it. Keep presentation and logic separated.
2. When you define theme functions with hook theme, you should call them theme_xxx instead of themename_/ modulename_.
3. Modules (and possible themes) have a weight weight that determines the order they are run with functions like hook_*_alter. Look at the install file for the devel module to see how this is done.

One or more of these things should help you out.